# Export Dataframe to Excel Table

Tags: python, dataframe, export-to-csv, openpyxl, xlsx

The simple code down below prints certain elements and their attributes in a dataframe.
It iterates through an XML files, looks for these elements and just prints them out

Code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
tree = ET.parse('1last.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for neighbor in root.iter('Description'):
    print(neighbor.attrib, neighbor.text)
for neighbor in root.iter('SetData'):
    print(neighbor.attrib)
for neighbor in root.iter('FileX'):
    print(neighbor.attrib) 
for neighbor in root.iter('FileY'):
    print(neighbor.attrib)
```

Output

[image: Here]

I want to export the output into a Excel table form but It doesn’t seem to work
I have tried this

`export_excel = root.to_excel (r'C:\Users\fsdf.LAPTOP-E8A1PPIN\Desktop\test\export_dataframe.xlsx', index = None, header=True)`

but I got the error  saying **“AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'to_excel'**

This my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProjectData>
<FINAL>
    <START id="ID0001" service_code="0x5196">
      <Docs Docs_type="START">
        <Rational>225196</Rational>
        <Qualify>6251960000A0DE</Qualify>
      </Docs>
      <Description num="1213f2312">The parameter</Description>
      <SetFile dg="" dg_id="">
        <SetData value="32" />
      </SetFile>
    </START>
    <START id="DG0003" service_code="0x517B">
      <Docs Docs_type="START">
        <Rational>23423</Rational>
        <Qualify>342342</Qualify>
      </Docs>
      <Description num="3423423f3423">The third</Description>
      <SetFile dg="" dg_id="">
        <FileX dg="" axis_pts="2" name="" num="" dg_id="" />
        <FileY unit="" axis_pts="20" name="TOOLS" text_id="23423" unit_id="" />
        <SetData x="E1" value="21259" />
        <SetData x="E2" value="0" />
      </SetFile>
    </START>
    <START id="ID0048" service_code="0x5198">
      <RawData rawdata_type="OPDATA">
        <Request>225198</Request>
        <Response>343243324234234</Response>
      </RawData>
      <Meaning text_id="434234234">The forth</Meaning>
      <ValueDataset unit="m" unit_id="FEDS">
        <FileX dg="kg" discrete="false" axis_pts="19" name="weight" text_id="SDF3" unit_id="SDGFDS" />
        <SetData xin="sdf" xax="233" value="323" />
        <SetData xin="123" xax="213" value="232" />
        <SetData xin="2321" xax="232" value="23" />
      </ValueDataset>
    </START>
</FINAL>
</ProjectData>
```

This is what I would want the table to look like.
[image]

Comment: `to_excel` is not a member function of `ElementTree`. It is part of `pandas`. You need to first decide what should be the structure of the table should be and then create a `pandas` dataframe accordingly. Alternatively you can also look at other excel packages like `openpxyl` and `xlsxwriter`

Comment: Can you give me more information regarding this . I have imported pandas to my code

Comment: what should be the structure of your table

Comment: @abhilb, I also added the xml file and an example of how I think its the best way the table should be. Maybe there are better approaches on what format should the data be displayed on the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to use a library such as `openpyxl` to write the Excel file directly. The following shows how this could be done:

```
import openpyxl    
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with open('1last.xml') as f_input:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f_input, 'lxml')

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.title = "Sheet1"

ws.append(["Description", "num", "text"])

for description in soup.find_all("description"):
    ws.append(["", description['num'], description.text])

ws.append(["SetData", "x", "value", "xin", "xax"])

for setdata in soup.find_all("setdata"):
    ws.append(["", setdata.get('x', ''), setdata.get('value', ''), setdata.get('xin', ''), setdata.get('xax', '')])

wb.save(filename="1last.xlsx")
```

This would create an Excel file looking like:

[image: Excel screenshot]

Comment: thank you for your answer. How would I parse these to an Excel file. The code runs succesfully though

Comment: Sorry, the copy/paste missed off the last save line

Comment: thank you, the code work with that part of xml from above but when using a bigger xml files that has the same names and attributes I get the following error : ***UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 64271: character maps to <undefined>***

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?  Are you able to give me a link to the file that is causing the problem?

Comment: I fixed it :  changed it into ***with open('result.xml',  encoding="utf8") as f_input:***

Comment: In Python 3.x, you could try changing the encoding using `with open('1last.xml', encoding='utf-8') as f_input:`

Comment: I'm having a problem. I just used a files that instead Description<>Meaning, num<>text_id , xin<>xmin , xax<>xmax . The output file prints the delcared variables but doesnt get anything from the xml file and parses it to the excel file. I did the renaming right

Comment: I'd need to see an example of this other xml file, use something like pastebin and post a link to the file here

Comment: I decided to go for another approach due to the fact that this one was creating many rows. I have been working on something new just got stuck, the order seems to be random. If you have time please have a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59269185/oder-of-xml-to-csv-not-right . I'm open for simpler approach on how to achieved the wanted results